# Validate form agaisnt modified selectable values in Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel, validation

I have this form.

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'ArticlesController@store', 'method' => 'post', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
   <div class="form-group">
      Form::select('size', array(
        'L' => 'Large', 
        'S' => 'Small'
     ));
   </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The user will have a dropdown list to select Large (value: L) or Small (value: S). But if the user, let say, changes the value of any of those options using the dev tools, or whatever.

How can I validate the form if the user sends the **'size'** field with a value that wasn't originally in the select options?

I mean, how can I check that the sent value is **L** or **S**, but not anything else.

Because the user could easily edit the form and send whatever value he wants to send, he could send a value that wasn't suppose to be sent.

I can do that using the validate class, but if instead of a 2 options list it is a 100 options list that'd be impossible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can validate that:

```
$request->validate(['size' => 'required|in:L,S']);
```

this part after pipe "`|in:L,S'`" is used to check if the $request attribute value is equal to any value in that rule.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-in